# Freeware to dismount locked USB drive

Tags: windows-7, usb, software-rec, unmounting

I'm searching for free software to dismount locked USB drives.

Sometimes when you want to dismount drive under Windows 7 it says that it is locked by some process. I need something that can do the job and dismount it in a proper way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [EjectUSB](http://www.portablefreeware.com/?id=1425).

> **Synopsis:** EjectUSB is a free tool (just 286 KB) for quickly closing apps running from a
>   USB drive and ejecting the drive from
>   safe removal. It will automatically
>   close all programs running from the
>   drive EjectUSB was run from (host
>   drive), close any explorer windows
>   open to the host drive, remove Windows
>   MUI and MRU entries and recent
>   document shortcuts related to the host
>   drive, and attempt to eject the host
>   drive when done. It can also interface
>   with various utilities to aid in drive
>   ejection.
>
> **License:** Freeware/Open Source
>
> **System Requirements:** Win98 / WinME / WinNT / Win2K / WinXP / Vista / Win7